# Subscribe to changes of an arbitrary web page

Tags: website, change-tracking

There is a plain (html) web page, which occasionally gets updated with text information. Is there any way to get notified (by any means) if this particular web page content is changed whereas website doesn't provide any subscription mechanism?

Comment: periodically programatically scrape the site, record the MD5/SHA sum, compare to previous invocation and send an alert/email when it changes.    In Linux you can use curl or wget or a number of other tools, and wrap it in a trivial bash script.

Answer (score 1):

#### Linux (and WSL)

#### <sup>You should be able to use the following even in the  Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)</sup>

Under Linux you can use `wget` with the `-N` option (timestamp) from the directory in which you have previously downloaded the page.

```
wget -N  https://example.com/your_page.html
```

It will download only a new version of the file, asking to the server the timestamp. `wget` will give a different output in case the download succeed or not.

- File downloaded

  > HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
- Not downloaded because it has the same timestamp

  > HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 304 Not Modified

So at the end you can build your command-line or a script similar to

```
wget -N https://example.com/your_page.html 2>&1 \
      | grep "304 Not Modified" >/dev/null \
      && echo "Not downloaded, old one" \
      || echo "There is a new file"
```

Notes:

- `-N` activate the [timestamp usage](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Time_002dStamping)
- `2>&1` redirect the standard error to the standard output, needed for the following `grep`
- `| grep "304 Not Modified"` pipe the output of the previous command (`wget`) as input of `grep` that selects the line with "304 Not Modified". It exit with status `0` (true) if it founds a match.
- `&&` *logic and* (aka `then`) execute the following command if the previous exit status is 0. You can omit this part.
- `||` *logic or* (aka `else`) execute the following command if the exit status is not 0.
- each `\` is used in the shell to go to a new line and  it must be the last character of the line
- change `echo this or that` with your command...

---

**Final remarks**

With `wget -O - | md5sum` you can create a checksum to reuse the next time without the need to keep a local copy...